# boxes do not appear on chrome

Tags: javascript

on my login page i have radio buttons for a new member and an existing member.
if the user click the existing member's button - only then 
2 input boxes appear : user name and pw.
it works on IE but it does not work on chrome.
This is the script. 
Can someone help ??

```
<script> 
    function dispLoing(val) 
    { 
        var obj=document.getElementById?document.getElementById("loginForm").style : document.all? document.all.loginForm : document.loginForm; 

        if (val=="new") 
        { 
            document.all.login(0).checked=true; 
            obj.display="none"; 
        } 
        if (val=="existing") 
        { 
            document.all.login(1).checked=true; 
            obj.display=""; 
        } 
    } 
</script> 


<td> 
   <div id="loginForm" style="position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:80;display:none;"> 
         <table border=0> 
            <tr> 
              <td><font style="font-size: 14px">Username:</font></td> 
               <td><input type="text" name="username" style="width: 100px; height:17px; font-size: 12px;"></td> 
             </tr> 
             <tr> 
             <td><font style="font-size: 14px">Password:</font></td> 
             <td><input type="password" name="pass" style="width: 100px; height:17px; font-size: 12px;"></td> 
            </tr> 
           </table>
```

Comment: Next time use "code" button to mark code as code.

Comment: Also, consider placing all of the relevant code. Where's the rest of the table? Where's the element that triggers dispLoing()? Also, try expanding the line with all of the ? marks in it to avoid things being confusing to you. Lastly, Why not ask Chrome? It's got a debugger that will tell you why it won't work - (Hit Ctrl-Shift-I)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `document.all`, it doesn't work in all browsers. `document.getElementById` is standardized and works everywhere.